# How to manipulate a validatedValue for a validation constraints

Tags: java, spring

I'm using a pattern constraint to ensure a sort code is just digits. If a invalid character is entered I want the specific character to be output in the message. I'm not sure how to get the invalid characters from the validatedValue. I have it setup now to just out put what was input right now so say you entered

11-22-33

you would get: *Fields contain invalid characters: sort code '11-22-33'*

but I want: *Fields contain invalid characters: sort code '-'*

My current code is:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]*$", message="Fields contain invalid characters: sort code '${validatedValue}'")
private String sortCode;
```

Comment: And what error message do you want to return if the input contains more than one invalid character, for example "foo-bar"?

Comment: I think just first invalid character it find, so 'f'. A list of invalid characters would be ok as well but I'm not too worried either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like that:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]*$", message = "Fields contain invalid characters: sort code '${validatedValue.replaceAll(\"\\\\d\", \"\")}'")
private String sortCode;
```

The code above will produce the following message for `sortCode` of `1a2b3-D`:

```
Fields contain invalid characters: sort code 'ab-D'
```